# Elixir: How to avoid deeply nested case statements?

Tags: elixir

Let's say I have a function `main_function` that depends on the result of three other functions which can each either return `{:ok, result}` or `{:error, error}`. How can I avoid having deeply nested case statements that feel like callback hell in javascript.

Example:

```
def func1(input) do
  case SOMECONDITION do
    {:ok, result} ->
      {:ok, result}
    {:error, error} ->
      {:error, error}
  end
end

def func2(input) do
  case SOMECONDITION do
    {:ok, result} ->
      {:ok, result}
    {:error, error} ->
      {:error, error}
  end
end

def func3(input) do
  case SOMECONDITION do
    {:ok, result} ->
      {:ok, result}
    {:error, error} ->
      {:error, error}
  end
end

def main_function(input) do
  case func1(input) do
    {:ok, result} ->
      case func2(result) do
        {:ok, result} ->
          case func3(result) do
            {:ok, result} ->
              {:ok, EXPECTED_OUTCOME}
            {:error, error} ->
              {:error, error}
          end
        {:error, error} ->
          {:error, error}
      end
      {:error, error} ->
        {:error, error}  
    end
  end
end
```

This just doesn't feel right...

Comment: I think you can use `with` statement. https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.SpecialForms.html#with/1

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**[Edit]: I've added a convenience link to a great talk that covers this concept, as well as solutions for more sophisticated needs from ElixirConf 2018 below.**

Don't worry - Elixir has you covered. You want [this special form](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.SpecialForms.html#with/1): `with/1`

`with/1` will continue executing functions if and only if they match the expected outcome.

You're main function essentially looks something like:

```
def main_function(input) do
  with {:ok, result_1} <- func1(input),
       {:ok, result_2} <- func2(result_1),
        ...,
  do: {:ok, EXPECTED_OUTCOME}
end
```

When it can't find a match, say because there's a tuple like `{:error, _error}` the special form will return the first error encountered and stop executing the functions.

You can also add an else condition. An example where I've used this is when a user may expect some action that requires a lot of functions to complete, and I want to alert them of the same thing regardless of where it failed:

```
def main_function(input) do
  with {:ok, result_1} <- func1(input),
       {:ok, result_2} <- func2(result_1),
        ... do
    {:ok, EXPECTED_OUTCOME}
  else
    _error ->
      {:error, "Couldn't complete action"}
  end
end
```

#### Additional Resources:

Here's an amazing talk from the author of Credo on this concept, courtesy of ElixirConf 2018: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ycpNi701aCs&t=473s

Here's a great post on `with/1`: https://www.erlang-solutions.com/blog/exploring-with-the-elixir-special-form.html

Comment: That is an interesting approach. But let's say `func1` and `func2` are writing to the db. If `func1` returns an error I don't want `func2` to be executed at all. Would this be the case?

Comment: This handles it! It stops execution at the first non-match, so in this case the very first error - so func2 won't attempt execution without func1 being successful.

Comment: Do not forget the `else` clause, quite useful!

Answer (score 4):

Answering the comment on the accepted answer:

> That is an interesting approach. But let's say `func1` and `func2` are writing to the db. If `func1` returns an error I don't want `func2` to be executed at all. Would this be the case?

There is also another option, if you are using **Ecto**.

Let's say `func1`, `func2`, and `func3` *all* write to the DB, but the steps fail at `func2`, which means `func1` has already written to the DB.

And let's say they return `{:ok, result}` or `{:error, error}`.

[`Ecto.Multi`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Multi.html) to the rescue!

```elixir
alias Ecto.Multi
alias MyApp.Repo

def main_function(input) do
  result =
    Multi.new()
    |> Multi.run(:result1, fn _ -> func1(input) end)
    |> Multi.run(:result2, &func2(&1.result1))
    |> Multi.run(:result3, &func3(&1.result2))
    |> Repo.transaction()

  case result do
    {:ok, %{result1: _, result2: _, result3: _}} ->
      {:ok, EXPECTED_OUTCOME}

    {:error, error, _changes_so_far} ->
      {:error, error}
  end
end
```

With Multi, returning an error tuple will abort any further operations and make the whole multi fail. Also, since it's using a transaction, any that succeeded will all be rolled back.